# MPMoviewcontroller and AVPlayer with custom control

Tags: ios, avplayer

Hi sorry for this old question. I have tried to research but still have no solution :(.
I need to implement a video controller with my own control buttons. Base on [apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
I use `MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;` and add my own layer over `player.view`. There is a problem with my `seekForward` function. I can not set `player.currentPlaybackTime = player.duration` (when user press seekForward until reaching the end of the movie). I want to switch to AVPlayer but there is another issues. How can I custom with my own button?. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue with MPMoviePlayerController. Also We can't add more than one MPMoviePlayerController in a same view. For this, I have created a custom player using AVPlayer having basic features. You can download it from my github account [HRVideoPlayer](https://github.com/hemkaran/HRVideoPlayer). Let me know if you want more detailed version. I have built my own video player having all functionalities like Seeking, volume control, brightness control, replace currentItem, Repeat and shuffle.

Comment: Since I am new to stackOverflow, so I can't add comments here, so I posted the answer.

Comment: Could you share the detailed version or full code for your custom video player. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I am working on a customized AVPlayer and I was wondering whether you (@hemkaran_raghav ) can share the detailed version of player you made. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Kahsn, here it is https://github.com/mikeMTOL/KSVideoPlayer. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: A Custom Video Player for iOS with AVFoundation in Swift http://binarymosaic.com/custom-video-player-for-ios-with-avfoundation/